# keypress event - handle multiple scanners concurrently

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode-scanner

I have a requirement to handle the input of up-to four scanners. These scanners can read bar-codes concurrently. Depending on their configured prefix, I need to load the bar-code in the correct text-box on my web page.

Assuming the scanners will be prefixed with 1, 2, 3, 4. Here is my code -

```
<input type="text" id="barcode1" />
<input type="text" id="barcode2" />
<input type="text" id="barcode3" />
<input type="text" id="barcode4" />
```

Above text boxes may/may not have the focus, hence using `addEventListener` for `keypress` below

```
<script>
    var barcodewithPrefix = "";

    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) {
            barcodewithPrefix += e.key;
        }
        else {

            var prefix = barcodewithPrefix.substring(0, 1);
            var barcode = barcodewithPrefix.substring(1, barcodewithPrefix.length); //remove the prefix and get the actual barcode

            //display in correct text box
            if (prefix == "1") {
                document.querySelector("#barcode1").value = barcode; 
            }
            else if (prefix == "2") {
                document.querySelector("#barcode2").value = barcode;
            }
            else if (prefix == "3") {
                document.querySelector("#barcode3").value = barcode;
            }
            else{
                document.querySelector("#barcode4").value = barcode;
            }

            barcodewithPrefix = ""; //clear for next input
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

</script>
```

This code is working fine for one scanner as well as for keyboard input.

However, it does not run correctly if there is more than one scanner and are used concurrently. The bar-codes digits get all jumbled up and doesn't appear correctly in their respective text-box.

I understand this is expected - looking at the code where each input char is interpreted with a keypress event.

Can anyone please guide how can I make it work. Are there any workarounds to tackle it?

Thank you!

Comment: I highly doubt it is possible.

Comment: Barcode scanners are recognized as keyboard input. Javascript will just see a bunch of input coming in, not knowing the difference in source. This could be as simple as the user not using them at the same time, but having some kind of delay.

Comment: hmm... thank you for your reply. 
Shall I assume there is no way in js to receive the bar-code all together rather than receiving each char/digit?